# How can I get the value of fetch async in then statement when I am using Swal?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch, sweetalert2

This is my source code. I am using [sweetalert2.all.min.js](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)  to use `swal` popup. Now I have a question, How can I access the returned value from API endpoint in `then` statement? I also mark it in the source code.
This is the source:

```
Swal.fire({
        title: 'Welcome',
        text: "Enter Username and Password",
        html:
            '<input id="username_input" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Enter Username">',
        input: 'password',
        inputPlaceholder: 'Enter Password',
        inputAttributes: {
            autocapitalize: 'off'
        },
        showCancelButton: false,
        confirmButtonText: 'Login',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        preConfirm: (passwordEntered) => {
            var usernameEntered = document.getElementById('username_input').value;
            return fetch("...my_endpoint.../checkusername/" + usernameEntered + "/" + passwordEntered)
                .then(response => {
                    response.text().then((val) => {
                        return val   // **: I need to get this value in * place
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    return "ERROR";
                })
        },
        allowOutsideClick: () => {
            !Swal.isLoading()
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        alert(result.value);  // *: I need to access the value from **
    })
```

So, When I log result's value, I get value of `passwordEntered` variable.

Comment: Maybe add `return` before `response.text()`

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes I can access anything if I return before response.text() method. But in this situation I never can access response text in 'then' statement. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By dropping the `.then()` syntax and switching to `async/await` :

```
preConfirm: async (passwordEntered) => {
    var usernameEntered = document.getElementById('username_input').value;

    const response = await fetch("...my_endpoint.../checkusername/" + usernameEntered + "/" + passwordEntered);
    return await response.text();
},
```

Comment: Although async/await is a more clear syntax, it's basically a syntactic sugar of Promises so it can't solve a problem that regular Promise can't.

Comment: It works. And also the main function would be async.

Comment: @MoshFeu It can solve the same problems _and_ spare you a few headaches while solving them in two lines. Between a `.then().then()` week long headache and two lines of `async/await`, I chose my side.

Comment: Of course. I'm a big fan of async await I just wanted to clarify that point so OP wouldn't get the impression that there is a problem with Promises.